# How to search for local documents by content from Windows 10 taskbar search

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, desktop-search

How to search for local documents by content from Windows 10 taskbar search?

Taskbar search searches local documents only by file name. How to integrate it with proper windows indexed content search? AKA windows desptop search? The content indexed search works for me from File Explorer well. I would like to use content indexed search also from taskbar search, not having to constantly open File Explorer app. Most Linux desktops have this integrated better. How to do it for Windows?

Proof that my desktop search works, and multi word query is supported, at least from File Explorer:
[image]

Same query fails in taskbar search:
[image]

**UPDATE**
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎10/‎04/‎2021
OS build    19042.867
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

Comment: Understanding what version of Windows you are using is important, as answers have changed, even in the last year between 1903/1909 and 2004/20H2.

Comment: @Ramhoud Fair point. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Taskbar Search, use the three dots  ...  upper right to get to Search Settings.  This is the "new" Windows Settings approach.

In there, you can customize search settings which pulls up the Classic Search Settings.

The first window is Location. Make sure USERS and Outlook are both selected plus anything else you wish. I have several locations.

Click on Advanced and then File Types and see all the types that are indexed.  Look through and see if anything like DOCX or PDF is unselected for some reason and select it.

Look in DOCX, XLSX, PDF and so on, down at the bottom and make sure Content is selected. Many types can only find file name but numerous types can also find content. I use this extensively.

If you change Location or File Types (you likely will) in Advanced options you can Rebuild the Index. Do this in the evening and let the machine run overnight.

Here is a Navigation Screen Shot to assist you.

[image]

You may wish to constrain Task Bar Search to Documents (not All) when searching for local Content.

Comment: as you can see in my first screenshot, my desktop search generally works, and works well, just not from taskbar search. If my search settings were incorrect, or missing, File Explorer also would not be able to find anything, would it?

Comment: If you fix the location and indexing, the search should work from both places.  Windows Explorer search can find things depending on the folder where you opened the Search.

Comment: Also, when you are searching your own disk for content, it may be worthwhile to set Taskbar Search to Documents (not All).